# Is there a simpler way to check what N child of some parent an element is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

An example:

```
parent
 0 child-a
 1 child-b
   sub-child
 2 child-c
   sub-child
   sub-child
```

This works currently in my fiddle, just wondering if there is a cleaner way to go about it. But If a child-(a|b|c) is clicked, the corresponding index is returned (much like jQuery's .index()... but if you click a child's sub-child, you get that same corresponding index.

Code:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
    // when clicking , show which top level parent element it's in
    var element_to_stop_at = $j(".the_top_level_container");

    $j(document).click(function(event) {
        var target = $j(event.target);
        var index_of_top_level_element = 0;
        var found_target = false;

        var current = target;
        while ((current.length > 0) && current.attr("class") != element_to_stop_at.attr("class")) {
            current = current.parent();
        }

        var children = current.children();

        current = children.first();
        while (current.length > 0 && index_of_top_level_element < children.length) {
            if (current.has(target).length > 0 || current[0] == target[0]) {
                found_target = true;
                break;
            }
            current = current.next();
            index_of_top_level_element += 1;
        }
        if (false == found_target) {
            index_of_top_level_element = -1;
        }


        console.log("is the " + index_of_top_level_element + " th/nd/rd element in the containing element");
    });
});​
```

Is there a simplar / quicker way to do this?

Basically, I would like the functionality of .index(), but if I click a child of one of `.the_top_level_container`'s children, it should return the same index.

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DerNalia/4LSzt/

• click any of the 3 sections boxed/bordered in
• The console will give the index of the `the_top_level_container`'s children that the clicked element is a part of

Comment: Include the relevant code in the question as well, please, don't just link to a jsFiddle.

Comment: From the title it sounds like you want the [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method. I suggest that you review the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: I can't test your fiddle at the moment. But can't you just use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index) with a selector for the parent element?

Comment: Updated with details, and a simple example. hope this helps.

Comment: That's a big DEMO, can't you sum it a bit?

Comment: check the example at the bottom of my question. that's the simple version =p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting at the `e.target`, use `.closest()` to get to the child of the top level container, then use `.index()`.

```
                   // child selector-------------------------v
var idx = $j(event.target).closest('.the_top_level_container > *')
                          .index();
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/4LSzt/22/

Comment: holy balls, I had no idea it could be simplified that much O_O

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you need but check the `index()` method:

http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: kind of. Except, I want to be able to get that index from each of the children's children.  I've edited my question to be more clear.